# Header Request too long in Error 400 on Chrome, but works fine on firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, web

AccountController

This is my SignMeIn Claim function

```
 private void SignMeIn(User user, bool isPersistent)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
                new Claim(Global.CustomClaimTypes.UserId, user.UserId),
                new Claim(Global.CustomClaimTypes.UserType, user.UserType),
                new Claim(Global.CustomClaimTypes.UserModules, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user.Rights)),


                // ISSUE 001 - ONLY ON CHROME. WORKS FINE ON FIREFOX! - 05/06/2022
                // Too heavy claim for store. Causing ERROR 400, data requested from the server is too long.
                // Comment the code below to remove claim request from session!
                new Claim(Global.CustomClaimTypes.UserStores, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user.Stores)) // Original Code
            };

            var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Global.AuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
            var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
            authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, id);
        }
```

I'm using claims to save all user data into its current session, and can easily access Global variables and functionalities.
It work's fine calling out in Login Function

```
 public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var user = _userService.VerifyUser(model.InputUserID, ClsRijndael.EncryptRijndael(model.InputPassword));
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        SignMeIn(user, model.RememberMe);
                        // Calling the fetch function - 05/06/2022
                        FetchStore(user);

                        //_sessionService.Set<string>(Global.SessionKeys.UserImage, user.ImageData);

                        if (user.UserType == "PCP")
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Main", "PCP");
                        }
                        else if (user.UserType == "SIC")
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Main", "SIC");
                        }
                        else if (user.UserType == "CCP")
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Main", "CCP");
                        }

                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
                    }
                }
                return View(model);
            }
            catch (AuthenticationException)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "There is a problem with your account, please contact your administrator.");
                return View(model);
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }
```

But if I run on Chrome, it gives the **Error 400** on specific that has quite a load of data.
[CHROME ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtyVg.png)

**BUT IT WORKS FINE ON FIREFOX**

Solutions I've tried:

- clearing all the cookies and it doesn't seem to work.
- adding a new claim outside the controller, but I haven't seen the fitting article for it so far.
- web.server maxRequestLength = 'maximum amount'

Comment: What's the response you request on the page via `curl`?

Comment: I'm just using IIS express

Comment: Can you paste the header and body of the request and the response as text?

Comment: I figured that it was a security of chrome and it's hard to configure. I fixed it by going around the header. Instead of calling all data in a wrap session for global access, I called the method on each controller instead. But thank you for your input.